# I don't have access to custom claims from firestore security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have set a custom claim using the firebase admin sdk. I have successfully use it to control access in the frontend and even with the RTDB, but I'm not able to use it with the Firestore database. Here is my security rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.admin == true;  
    } 
  }
}
```

Here is the code in my app:

```
   const users = []
   firebase.firestore().collection('users')
    .get()
    .then(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        users.push(doc.data())
      })
    })
    .then(() => {
      commit('setUsersList', users)
      commit('setLoading', false)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Error getting documents:', error)
      commit('setLoading', false)
    })
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
Error: Missing or insufficient permissions
```

Comment: Please add the code which is causing the error

Comment: Hi. I edited my question with my app code

Comment: The [Cloud Firestore Security Rules Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#properties) documentation states "If using custom authentication, request.auth.token also contains any custom claims specified by the developer."  So, unless the admin claim is missing / incorrect in your token or I'm missing something, I don't see why it wouldn't work.  Hopefully, someone else may have the answer

Comment: Can you force a refresh of the ID token for the user? From my asking around that may be needed to get the custom claim to show up in the security rules.

Comment: I did a refresh token with `getIdToken(true)` and I'm still getting the same error. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed the error. My mistake was that I was setting the permission using the admin sdk but I wasn't passing a boolean but a string.

For example, I was setting the user with uid '1' like this:
`axios.post('/admin/setadminprivileges/1/true')`

In my firebase functions I was getting:

```
app.post('/admin/setadminprivileges/:id/:permission', (req, res) => {
  const permission = req.params.permission // this is a string "true"
  const uid = req.params.id // "1"
  const payload = {admin: permission}
  admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, payload)
})
```

And now with this is working fine:

```
app.post('/admin/setadminprivileges/:id/:permission', (req, res) => {
  const permissionString = req.params.permission
  const permission = permissionString === 'true' // this is now a boolean
  const uid = req.params.id
  const payload = {admin: permission}
  admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, payload)
})
```

Thanks anyway. I knew it had to be a silly issue of my own, because Firebase is a solid product.

Comment: How to cloud functions work with strategy? Any suggestions?

Comment: @monjo Could you please post a screenshot where these claims are stored in   Firestore? Is it possible to set/remove some claims throw Cloud Firestore user interface?

Comment: I don't think there is a GUI where you can see or edit those claims.